# Comparing continuous data with categorical data (4 categories)? Severity of lesion in rats

Tags: correlation, experiment-design, ordinal-data

I have a study examining the effect of high fat diet in rats. We have many continuous variable such as weight, inflammatory blood cytokine levels, insulin, etc. However the major change we have found is a lesion with the joints which we have scored using a pathology scoring of 0,1,2,3 with 0 = healthy, no lesion and 3= most severe lesion. We want to examine if there is any relationship between any of the severity of the lesion. i.e. If the rat is heavier, is it likely to have a higher grade of lesion score. The study has 40 rats. Would be grateful if anyone can highlight if this has been addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[Ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) is what you are looking for, since the lesion severity values are discrete, but ordered. Treating it as categorical would destroy their order relation.

You also don't want a linear regression model, since that could predict values like $1.5$ or even outside the $[0,3]$ range.

If you are going to perform your analysis with R, I suggest you to use `polr` from the `MASS`package (see [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-51.4/topics/polr))

Answer (score 0):

The ANOVA test is typically used for comparing the means and variances between continuous measurements with a dependent variable with more than 2 classes. If you have any categorical measurement data then you can use Chi2. I found this reference reasonably useful: http://www.saedsayad.com/categorical_numerical.htm

Comment: Unortunatelly, it's the other way around. It's a categorical varaible (lesion severity) caused by a numerical one (weight)